# How to get colors in Vagrant shell?

Tags: bash, ssh, virtualbox, colors

In my terminal in Ubuntu, everything is colorful. The username is green, folders are blue and files are white:

[image]

However, if I login into vagrant `vagrant ssh` everything is black and white:

How can I add colors in vagrant shell?

[image]

I found this question which looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392434/how-to-configure-colors-in-vagrant-ssh-bash but they talking about `byobu` and `oh my zsh` that I have never heard of.

I am not looking for anything super fancy. Colored folders and username are enough.

Answer (score 1):

It should appear by default. No need to install specific package.
If you want simple colour coding, then you can try Bash-It.

### Installation

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it.git ~/.bash_it
~/.bash_it/install.sh
```

For more information 
https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it

Comment: So you saying something wrong with my vagrant?

Comment: Could be, for my vagrant I didnt do anything. It came by default.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get some basics with adding this to my `.bash_profile`

```
## Colorize the ls output ##
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1='\e[1;32m\u@\h: \e[1;34m\W\e[0m\$ '
```